# sqlite3 how to open database in another app

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a node app that creates the database like this:

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');
```

It also creates a bunch of tables and inserts rows into the tables.

Now, in another app, how do I load that database? I can't find that anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function will create a file named "test.db" if it doesn't exist already. In any other application (not just in Node, but every other programming language and also the CLI) you can just open that file in the same way.